# could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I got this error when I did "sqoop import ..." to hive.

```
namenode log
java.io.IOException: File /input/xxxx/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1492073551248_0012_m_000002_1/part-m-00002 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

```
datanode logs
slave1 :2017-04-13 19:58:59,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.149.141:50010, dest: /192.168.149.141:42764, bytes: 451, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_1492073551248_0012_m_000001_2_785964301_1, offset: 0, srvID: f274418e-04b6-4109-9521-e3c384c21ad0, blockid: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742751_1927, duration: 160511
```

```
datanode logs
slave2: 2017-04-13 19:58:02,389 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.149.141:34576, dest: /192.168.149.142:50010, bytes: 127362723, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_1492073551248_0012_m_000000_0_-417808976_1, offset: 0, srvID: 7f9110ab-8a1d-4a32-8219-aff6e3cd29b2, blockid: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742761_1937, duration: 64254909353
2017-04-13 19:58:02,389 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742761_1937, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2017-04-13 19:58:11,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.149.141:34588, dest: /192.168.149.142:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_1492073551248_0012_m_000002_1_-2031862368_1, offset: 0, srvID: 7f9110ab-8a1d-4a32-8219-aff6e3cd29b2, blockid: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742762_1938, duration: 63824306914
2017-04-13 19:58:11,270 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742762_1938, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2017-04-13 19:58:15,441 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write data to disk cost:349ms (threshold=300ms)
2017-04-13 19:58:15,769 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write data to disk cost:328ms (threshold=300ms)
2017-04-13 19:58:28,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.149.142:51700, dest: /192.168.149.142:50010, bytes: 134217728, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_1492073551248_0012_m_000003_1_-395038848_1, offset: 0, srvID: 7f9110ab-8a1d-4a32-8219-aff6e3cd29b2, blockid: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742763_1939, duration: 52247885321
2017-04-13 19:58:28,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742763_1939, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2017-04-13 19:58:28,689 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-219683118-192.168.149.138-1491539013447:blk_1073742764_1940 src: /192.168.149.142:51718 dest: /192.168.149.142:50010
```

Any idea to fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have enough space on the datanodes?

Comment: One of the datanodes DFS Used 10.45% and the other 4.12%
In addtion, the two datanode work normally.

Comment: Can you share the datanode logs ?

Comment: Sure,I pasted them above,you may have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CouldOnlyBeReplicatedTo,
I faced this same error when executing a large number of queries in a short span of time, so increased the threads on datanode and it fixed the problem by setting "dfs.datanode.handler.count". This exception is thrown for multiple reasons, visit the link to see is your case mentioned.